# jQueryUI draggable drag an element that's under another

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using draggable on an image that is under another transparent image with a higher z-index, is there any way to make draggable ignore objects with a certain class and look under them? Thanks

Comment: can you provide some code? maybe a working example of [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 7):

Found that CSS "pointer-events:none;" solves my problem.